# How can I get the screen size in Air?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3 code for Air, how can I get the screen width and height of the mobile device its running on?

Comment: AS3 doesn't read Android.  It only sees it as Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the Screen object for how to do that:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html#includeExamplesSummary

You can pretty easily figure out the dimensions of your NativeWindow, then find the screen it's on, and see the bounds by doing this:

```
var appBounds : Rectangle = stage.nativeWindow.bounds;
var screen : Screen = Screen.getScreensForRectangle( appBounds )[0];
var screenBounds : Rectangle = screen.bounds;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you use emulators on the desktop, Capabilities will return the resolution of you computer but not of emulated device.
Just simply use stage for this:

`trace(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);`

Comment: That is the better answer since stage is available at any DisplayObject.

Comment: This should be anyone who comes looking's answer. It is highly accurate and is initialized with the screen, while stage.nativeWindow.bounds remains null.

Comment: Would this read Android screen resolution properly?  Probably not, since it is the same as **Capabilities.screenResolutionY**

Answer (score 4):

another method, besides chubbard's answer, is to simply use the Capabilities class, which also works outside of AIR:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

var screenWidth:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var screenHeight:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

Comment: This only reports **Linux** screen resolution, which is different than **Android**'s screen resolution.  So for Android, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Set the stage scale mode to "no border":

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

 stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
```

Comment: What does this accomplish?